# Using Python to extract LinkedIn information

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I'm trying to visit, say a set of 8,000 LinkedIn profiles that belong to people who have a certain first name (just for example, let's say "Larry"), and then would like to extract the kinds of jobs each user has held in the past. Is there an efficient way to do this? I would need each Larry to be picked independently from one another; basically, traversing someone's network isn't a good way to do this. Is there a way to completely randomize how the Larry's are picked?

Don't even know where to start. Thanks.

Comment: Do you think that changing "Jerry" for "Larry" in your question and not providing any code, or sample, as you already did in this question asked 25 minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22888729/python-visiting-random-linkedin-profiles is going to generate different results?

Answer (score 0):

To Start:

Trying to crawl the response linkedin gives you on your browser would be almost suicidal.

Check their [APIs](http://developer.linkedin.com/apis) (particularly the [People's API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/people-search-api)) and their [code samples](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/code-samples).

Important disclaimer found in the People's API:

> People Search API is a part of our Vetted API Access Program. You must
>   apply here and get LinkedIn's approval before using this API.

MAYBE with that in mind you'll be able to write an script that queries and parses those APIs. For instance, retrieving users with Larry as a first name http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search?first-name=Larry

Once you get approved by Linkedin and you have retrieved some data from their APIs and tried some [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or [XML](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml) parsing (whatever the APIs return), you will have something more specific to ask.

If you still want to crawl the html returned by linkedin when you hit https://www.linkedin.com/pub/dir/?first=Larry&last=&search=Search take a look to [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)